# Using Firsebase + Firestore with Deno

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, deno

I'm trying to use `firebase`, specifically `firestore`, wtih Deno, but am running into issues with both `v8` and `v9` of the APIs.

For `v8` I follow [this tutorial from Deno](https://deno.com/deploy/docs/tutorial-firebase), but receive the error `Property firestore does not exist on firebase.`

```js
import "https://deno.land/x/xhr@0.1.2/mod.ts";

import firebase from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/firebase@8.10.0/app";
import "https://cdn.skypack.dev/firebase@8.10.0/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = { ... };
firebase.initializeApp( firebaseConfig, 'app' );
const firebaseApp = firebase.app( 'app' );
const db = firebase.firestore( firebaseApp );
```

The same error occurs for firebase version `8.7.0`.

For `v9` I get the error `Service firestore is not available`

```js
import "https://deno.land/x/xhr@0.1.2/mod.ts";

import { initializeApp } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/firebase@9.4.1/app";
import { getFirestore } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/firebase@9.4.1/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = { ... };
const firebaseApp = initializeApp( firebaseConfig );
const db = getFirestore( firebaseApp );
```

And if I don't pass `firebaseApp` to the `getFirestore` call I get the error `No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created.`

```js
...
const db = getFirestore();
```

### MRE

`v8.js`

```js
import "https://deno.land/x/xhr@0.1.2/mod.ts";

import firebase from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/firebase@8.10.0/app";
import "https://cdn.skypack.dev/firebase@8.10.0/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "apikey",
  authDomain: "pid.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "pid",
  storageBucket: "pid.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "msid",
  appId: "aid",
  measurementId: "mid"
};

firebase.initializeApp( firebaseConfig, 'app' );
const firebaseApp = firebase.app( 'app' );
const db = firebase.firestore( firebaseApp );
```

Run with `deno run v8.js`.

**output**

```sh
> deno run v8.js

Property 'firestore' does not exist on type '{ __esModule: boolean; initializeApp: (options: any, rawConfig: any) => any; app: { (name2: any): any; App: any; }; registerVersion: (libraryKeyOrName: any, version2: any, variant: any) => void; ... 4 more ...; INTERNAL: { ...; }; }'.
const db = firebase.firestore( firebaseApp );

> deno run --no-check v8.js

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'INTERNAL')
    e3.INTERNAL.registerComponent(new Component("firestore", function(e4) {
       ^
    at https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/@firebase/firestore@v2.4.0-WKZzTerrZCqDrKBg0YNc/dist=es2019,mode=imports/optimized/@firebase/firestore.js:11912:8
    at I (https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/@firebase/firestore@v2.4.0-WKZzTerrZCqDrKBg0YNc/dist=es2019,mode=imports/optimized/@firebase/firestore.js:11916:4)
    at https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/@firebase/firestore@v2.4.0-WKZzTerrZCqDrKBg0YNc/dist=es2019,mode=imports/optimized/@firebase/firestore.js:11920:1
```

---

`v9.js`

```js
import "https://deno.land/x/xhr@0.1.2/mod.ts";

import { initializeApp } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/firebase@9.4.1/app";
import { getFirestore } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/firebase@9.4.1/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "apikey",
  authDomain: "pid.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "pid",
  storageBucket: "pid.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "msid",
  appId: "aid",
  measurementId: "mid"
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp( firebaseConfig );
const db = getFirestore( firebaseApp );
```

Run with `deno run v8.js`

**output**

```sh
> deno run v9.js

Uncaught Error: Service firestore is not available
        throw Error(`Service ${this.name} is not available`);
              ^
    at Provider.getImmediate (https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/@firebase/component@v0.5.9-NRovvSCAF0YOkKLBn5pi/dist=es2019,mode=imports/optimized/@firebase/component.js:111:15)
    at Oa (https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/@firebase/firestore@v3.3.0-7hhS3yMUs2qdY64sdriE/dist=es2019,mode=imports/optimized/@firebase/firestore.js:9969:39)
    at file:///home/brian/Downloads/firebase-test/mrc-v9.ts:17:12


> deno run --no-check v9.js

Uncaught Error: Service firestore is not available
        throw Error(`Service ${this.name} is not available`);
              ^
    at Provider.getImmediate (https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/@firebase/component@v0.5.9-NRovvSCAF0YOkKLBn5pi/dist=es2019,mode=imports/optimized/@firebase/component.js:111:15)
    at Oa (https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/@firebase/firestore@v3.3.0-7hhS3yMUs2qdY64sdriE/dist=es2019,mode=imports/optimized/@firebase/firestore.js:9969:39)
    at file:///home/brian/Downloads/firebase-test/mrc-v9.ts:17:12
```

Comment: You seem to have missed some steps from the tutorial you followed. At minimum, you don't show that you include [the module for polyfilling `localStorage` in Deploy](https://deno.com/deploy/docs/tutorial-firebase#write-the-application).

Comment: @jsejcksn, in my script I do include the polyfilling module, however it does not affect the outcome of the errors I am receiving so I decided to leave it out of the example to make it more readable. From the tutorial it appears the polyfilling module is only used for accessing localStorage, and does not affect the firebase modules. Is your experience different?

Comment: I will add that at the end of the tutorial they provide the [finished source code](https://deno.com/examples/firebase.js) which gives the same errors. I’ve tried removing as much as possible from it to ensure the errors aren’t coming from something else, but they do indeed seem to be coming from the firebase module.

Comment: Without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it won't be possible to debug this because there are too many variables specific to your environment. However, based on the text of the error message you shared for the `v8` example, it seems like a compiler diagnostic rather than a runtime error. Try with `deno run --no-check` to skip type checking.

Comment: @jsejcksn, those are MREs, sans the API configuration details. Running with `--no-check` doesn't solve the issue, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you provide complete stdout/stderr from your console session, starting with the command used to run the deno process, including the full contents of all files involved in the module graph? (This is what I mean by MRE: Assume that the one trying to reproduce only has `deno` installed and nothing else.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240708/discussion-between-bicarlsen-and-jsejcksn).

Comment: If you come up with an answer after the discussion, post an answer here so that it can help the other community members as well.

Comment: After discussing with @jsejcksn, we believe the issue is with compatibility between the `firebase` module. I've raised this as an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/13277.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @bicarlsen, the issue is related to compatibility between the firebase module. And for that he has raised an [issue](http://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/13277) on Github.

Answer (score 0):

[A workaround has been posted in the GitHub thread](https://github.com/denoland/deploy_feedback/issues/131#issuecomment-1007323130) related to this issue. Instead of import from `https://cdn.skypack.dev/firebase@9.4.1/app`, you can import from `https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-app.js`, and similarly by replacing `app` in the URL for the other modules.

Comment: I'll leave the answer unaccepted until a more concrete resolution is made.